# Python Solver Module (logarithmic/exponential)

Tags: python, solver

I am working with an end-user who needs to implement a Solver, similar to the one in Microsoft Office Excel.

We looked into [numpy.linalg.solve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) but it seems to only solve linear equations. The equation the end-user wants to solve is actually logarithmic/exponential. I also only see a way to solve for a known value (x = 4), and we need to solve for a minimum value (x = as low as it can possibly be for the equation to still be true).

Does such a Python module exist?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to restate your question. If you want an equation g(x)=something to be true, but find the x as low as it can possibly be, then you are talking about minimizing x, constrained to the function g(x)=something. So what you have here is a constrained optimization problem. You want to minimise the function f(x)=x under some condition, e.g. g(x)<=5, x>=0. Check if this problem is convex and use something like 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html